# "Requested Bitrate is too small" - displaying JPEG2000 on Android

Tags: android, image, xamarin, jpeg, jpeg2000

I'm trying to display jpeg2000 image (jp2) on Android. I'm using Xamarin and **Csj2k** library (c# port of **jj2000** library).

```
CSJ2K.J2kImage.FromBytes(ImageBytes).As<Bitmap>()
```

**On Android 7.0 everything works OK.** 
But on Android 9.0 I'm receiving following error: 
**"Requested bitrate is too small"**

> $exception  System.InvalidOperationException: Requested bitrate is too small.
>
> at CSJ2K.j2k.codestream.reader.FileBitstreamReaderAgent..ctor
>
> at CSJ2K.j2k.codestream.reader.BitstreamReaderAgent.createInstance
>
> at CSJ2K.J2kImage.FromStream
>
> at CSJ2K.J2kImage.FromBytes*

As I am looking on implementation of library, this condition is a problem:

```
            // If cannot even read the first tile-part
            if (anbytes > tnbytes)
                throw new System.ApplicationException("Requested bitrate is too small.");
```

I tried to solve problem with custom parameters, but they're hard to understand for me - without any effects.

Answer (score 0):

I download CSJ2K, version is 3.0.0 in Xamarin.Android by Nuget package, and debug on Android 9.0, but have no problem.

Adding image jp2 in Asset file, and setting **AndroidAsset**

```
 imageview1 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);

        Bitmap bitmap;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            this.Assets.Open("file2.jp2").CopyTo(stream);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            bitmap = J2kImage.FromStream(stream).As<Bitmap>();
        }

        imageview1.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

This is my sample at github:

https://github.com/CherryBu/CSJ2KSample